# a chain visits an open set infinite amount of time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Given that $x_n$ is a Feller Markov chain in a compact metric space $X$, could anyone tell me how to show that the Markov chain visits every open set in the metric space infinite amount of time from any starting point if and only if $\mathbb P (x_n \in O)>0$? where $O$ is an open set in $X$.Thanks.

Feller mean, if $x_n\to x$ then $Pf(x_n)\to Pf(x)$ for any continous function $f$, where $P$ is the transition probability operator for the chain, right?